# RegEx-Bug? Expression not enough ")"

Tags: c#, regex

I have this line to match `ABC123457` or `123457`

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(ABC|[])[0-9]{7}$");
```

All online-regex-tester says that is correct and it working as expected.
Maybe a bug in `System.Text.RegularExpression` because of the empty `[]`?

Comment: Even when this is parsed as valid, `[]` is just the same as the empty string. Just omit it entirely (or use the `?` quantifier as shown by Wiktor).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `[]` in a .NET regex to denote an empty string. If you pasted your regex into a .NET regex testing site you would see

[image]

Actually, your expression is parsed as

- `^` - start of string
- `(` - start of a capturing group
- `ABC` - a literal substring
- `|` - or
- `[` - start of a character class

  - `])[0-9` - `]`, `)`, `[`, digits
- `]{7}`  - 7 occurrences
- `$` - end of string.

*There is no ending `)` here*.

To fix the current pattern, just use an optional non-capturing group:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(?:ABC)?[0-9]{7}$");
                           ^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3AABC%29%3F%5B0-9%5D%7B7%7D%5Cr%3F%24&i=ABC1234567%0D%0A1234567&o=m).

Comment: @user6537157 It is a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon). If you need to access Group 1 value (`match.Groups[1].Value`, to check if it is empty or `ABC`), use a capturing group, as you did in the original pattern. I surmised you used a group just for an alternation, sorry if that is not what you meant.

Comment: Its all fine, the link explains what I wanted to know. :)